# How i can pass my event to React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have parent component:

```
const DashboardPage = () => {const handleClick = (e) => {};
return (
<Container fluid>
  <Row>
    <Col className="p-0" md={2}>
      <div>
        <Sidebar handleClick={handleClick}/>
      </div>
    </Col>
    <Col className="p-0" md={9}>
      <div>
        <ChatBody handleClick={handleClick} />
      </div>
    </Col>
  </Row>
</Container>);};
```

And some child's:
1-st: ChatBody.js

```
 const ChatBody = () => {
   return (
  <Container fluid className="position-relative px-0"></Container>);
 };
```

2-nd: Sidebar.js

```
const Sidebar = ({ handleClick }) => {
return (
<div className="border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper">
  <SidebarButtons handleClick={handleClick} />
</div>)
;
};
```

And child in my Sidebar

```
const SidebarButtons = ({handleClick   }) => {

return (
  <div >
    <Row>
      <Col className="m-2">
        <Button
          className="mx-auto p-2 w-100"
          variant="success"
          onClick={() => handleClick("previous")}
        >
          previous
        </Button>
      </Col>

      <Col className="m-2">
        <Button
          className="mx-auto p-2 w-100"
          variant="success"
          onClick={() => handleClick("next")}
        >
          next
        </Button>
      </Col>
      <Col className="m-2">
        <Button
          className="mx-auto p-2 w-100 d-flex justify-content-around align-items-center"
          variant="light"
          onClick={() => handleClick("newMessages")}
          
        >
          newMessages
         
        </Button>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </div>
);
};
```

I need return my handleClick props into my ChatBody
How i can did it?

I try use this code in my DasboardPage component and i see my props,but i cant send it to my ChatBody

```
const handleClick = (action) => {
console.log( action);
};
```

And i try this, its worked!But i see console.log(buttonClick) only once!there is a suggestion that I just do not update the status of the button

```
const ChatBody = (buttonClick) => {
 useEffect(() => {console.log(buttonClick);}, [buttonClick]);
 return (
  <Container fluid className="position-relative px-0">
 
  </Container>);
 };
const DashboardPage = () => {const handleClick = (action) => {setButtonClick(action);};
const [buttonClick, setButtonClick] = useState(null);
return (
    <Container fluid>
      <Header />
      <Row>
        <Col className="p-0" md={2}>
          <div>
            <Sidebar  handleClick={handleClick}/>
          </div>
        </Col>
        <Col className="p-0" md={9}>
          <div>
            <ChatBody buttonClick={buttonClick}/>
          </div>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Plz help me:)

Answer (score 0):

Try passing `handleClick` prop from `Dashboard` component to `chatbody`

```
const ChatBody = ({ handleClick }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(handleClick);
  }, [handleClick]);

  return (
    <Container fluid className="position-relative px-0">
      {/* Your ChatBody content */}
    </Container>
  );
};

const DashboardPage = () => {
  const handleClick = (action) => {
    console.log(action);
  };

  return (
    <Container fluid>
      <Header />
      <Row>
        <Col className="p-0" md={2}>
          <div>
            <Sidebar handleClick={handleClick} />
          </div>
        </Col>
        <Col className="p-0" md={9}>
          <div>
            <ChatBody handleClick={handleClick} />
          </div>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Comment: i try this, and after click my btns i see  console.log(action) only  in DashboardPage 
and this 
 "action => {
    console.log(action);
  }"
in chatbody, but only at first rendering my components.